# Zombie.js pressButton how to access post-ajax version of the browser?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mocha.js, zombie.js

I'm using zombie.js to automate testing of browser actions, in this case clicking on a button to submit a form.

Outside of the tests, in the real browser, when the button is clicked, an AJAX request is triggered. When the AJAX request completes, two `div.alert` elements are added to the document body.

The test below presses the button and triggers the request, but when the test subsequently queries the document looking for the expected div elements, it can't find them. I believe the test is querying the "old" version of the document that exists before the AJAX call finishes. My question is: how can I access the version of the document that exists **after** the AJAX call finishes and adds the elements?

```
context("when visited on the 'new' page", function(){
  before(function(){  return browser.visit('/');  });
  before(function(){  return browser.clickLink('new');  });

  context("when submitted with invalid values", function(){
    before(function(){
      return browser.pressButton("Submit")
    })

    it("flash should include error messages", function(){
      var messages = browser.queryAll(".alert")
      console.log(messages)
      expect(messages.length).toEqual(2)
    })
  })
})
```

Note: I have been looking into the zombie.js tests, and find use of `async` and `await`, but when I try to use those keywords in my .js file, it doesn't recognize them. This may be a separate issue, but if the solution requires async/await, how do I enable mocha to recognize those keywords?

Comment: `async/await` is an ES7 feature. You could probably find a way to turn it on somehow. However, I don't see how that would help you. The issue is having your test wait for the DOM to be modified. I don't use Zombie at all but I do use Selenium which comes with functions that do just this. If Zombie does not have the equivalent, you could always poll the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the selenium recommendation

Comment: I need to amend my earlier comment: `async/await` did not make it into ES7 (=== ES2016). ES2016 has been approved like, yesterday (which I learned just now) but they've cut `async/await` from it. It may be part of the next revision of the language.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your ajax calls so that after updating the screen they dispatch an event against the body called e.g. "action-completed". Then in your tests you can create a listener function that returns a Promise that doesn't resolve until the event is received.

```
const actionAndWait = ( action, eventName ) => new Promise( resolve => {

    const listener = () => {
        browser.body.removeEventListener( eventName, listener );
        resolve();
    };

    browser.body.addEventListener( eventName, listener );
    action();
    browser.wait();

} );
```

Your 'before' would then call

```
return actionAndWait( () => browser.pressButton("Submit"), "action-completed" );
```